# ListBox issue can't get the ItemsSource from a custom class to output in the MainPage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I made a custom Class named MedinetParse that parses a webrequest. The parsed data should be showen in a listbox named mittSchemaListBox in the my MainPage. The problem that i'm facing now is that IF i write the parsing method in a custom class named MedinetParse the listbox showes nothing. Althought when i put a breakpoint at the very last line of code inside the parse method, i can see that mittSchemaListBox.ItemsSource have all the parsed items. Meanwhile if i move the parsing method into my MainPage.xaml.cs, then i will see all the parsed item in my listbox.

Here is my MedinetParsing class

```
namespace WindowsPhonePanoramaApplication1
{
public class MedinetParsing : MainPage
{
    //Defining class properties
    public string Placering { get; set; }
    public string Datum { get; set; }
    //Defining class methods
    public void parseResults(string myresponse)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myresponse))
        {
            return;
        }

        //Initiating a listbox and add item to it
        List<ItemViewModel> mittSchemaList = new List<ItemViewModel>();
        //Using HtmlAgilityPack to parse the HTMLcode from the response
        HtmlDocument htdoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htdoc.LoadHtml(myresponse);
        foreach (HtmlNode table in htdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='list-medium']/tbody[1]/tr[@class]"))
        {
            //Removing ChildNode
            table.ChildNodes.RemoveAt(3);
            string itemValue = table.InnerText;
            //Changing the parsed date into a DateTime
            string d;
            DateTime datum = DateTime.Parse(itemValue.Remove(11));
            d = datum.ToString("D");
            //Adding items to the listbox
            mittSchemaList.Add(new ItemViewModel() { Datum = d, Placering = itemValue.Remove(0, 15) });
        }
        mittSchemaListBox.ItemsSource = mittSchemaList;

    }
}
}
```

Here is the code that initiate the parse:-

```
    public void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
        MedinetWebRequest mittschema = new MedinetWebRequest();
        MedinetParsing mittparse = new MedinetParsing();
        mittschema.url = "https://medinet.se/cgi-bin/doctor.pl?action=login&customer=******&language=se";
        Action callback = () => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => mittparse.parseResults(mittschema.myresponse));
        mittschema.getrequest(callback); 
    }
```

And lastly this is my Listbox:-

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" Name="mittSchemaListBox" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                            <Canvas Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0" Background="#FFE5001B">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Datum}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="100" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" />
                            </Canvas>
                            <StackPanel Width="311">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Placering}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,10" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="36" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Normal" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Been trying to fix this issue for the last few hours and not getting anywhere, i decided to ask here. Hope someone can tell me what is the problem.

Comment: several questions: where the Listbox is declared? in the MainPage? why do you inherit MedinetParsing from MainPage? you are creating a new instance of the MedinetParsing in the MainPage_Loaded, why do you need it? - please clarify this moment in your question

Comment: Let me start by saying that the new instance of MedinetParing in the MainPage_Loaded is to start the parseResults method. I corrected the posted code, which was miss-typed. The reason i used Class MedinetParsing : MainPage is to get access to the mittSchemaListBox which is the name of the ListBox in .xaml. Now to your last question about Listbox declaretion in MainPage. I'm not sure where to declare that coz my Action callback... is the last line of code to excute so any code line efter this will not be read.

Comment: well, you should not use class MedinetParsing : MainPage to get an access to the mittSchemaListBox, it is just another list box, it is absolutely not related to the shown one.

Comment: how do i get access to mittSchemaListBox from within my custom class then?

Comment: don't do it on the custom class, do it in the MainPage class. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not answer my question last night so here is the answer.

Again after few hours getting back and forth with my code i just found out a solution that fits my app. The solution is that i changed this line of code in my MedinetParsing class

```
mittSchemaList.Add(new ItemViewModel() { Datum = d, Placering = itemValue.Remove(0, 15) });
```

with this one:-

```
App.ViewModel.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() {Datum=d,Placering=itemValue.Remove(0,15)});
```

Got rid of this line of code:-

```
mittSchemaListBox.ItemsSource = mittSchemaList;
```

Now it is working like it should and i'm happy ;).
Hope this will help someothers if they face such a problem.

Yours

Answer (score 0):

Ok, according to your comments, you are doing it the the wrong way. Try this one:

1. You don't need the new MedinetParing class, just move methods directly to the MainPage code-behind
2. Update MainPage_Loaded method as follows:

(or consider to move this code to ViewModel as you are using it somehow here)

```
public void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
    {
        App.ViewModel.LoadData();
    }

    MedinetWebRequest mittschema = new MedinetWebRequest();
    mittschema.url = "https://medinet.se/cgi-bin/doctor.pl?action=login&customer=******&language=se";
    Action callback = () => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => this.parseResults(mittschema.myresponse));
    mittschema.getrequest(callback); 
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public class MedinetParsing //  : MainPage -- we don't need this inheritance
{
    private readonly MainPage _mainPage;

    public MadinetParsing(MainPage mainPage)
    {
        _mainPage = mainPage;
    }

    // your code here

    // use the next line instead of commented one
    // mittSchemaListBox.ItemsSource = mittSchemaList;
    _mainPage.mittSchemaListBox.ItemsSource = mittSchemaList;
}
```

But, as I'm said before, the best solution will be to do parse in the ViewModel and use binding to populate the ListBox.

Comment: I know i can do the whole parsing in the MainPage and it is working. Though i still wondering if there is somehow a way to parse the data in another class?

Comment: Thanks for your help and time, i just found a much suitable way to do it. I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Could not answer my question right now but here is the answer, i will update it later. Again after few hours getting back and forth with my code i just found out a solution that fits my app.

The solution is that i changed this line of code in my MedinetParsing class
    'code'mittSchemaList.Add(new ItemViewModel() { Datum = d, Placering = itemValue.Remove(0, 15) }); 'code'
with this one:-
    'code'App.ViewModel.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() {Datum=d,Placering=itemValue.Remove(0,15)}); 'code'
Got rid of this line of code:-
    'code' mittSchemaListBox.ItemsSource = mittSchemaList; 'code'